# Discord JS TOKEN + os.getenv

Tags: python, environment-variables, discord, discord.py

### Hey there,

I have decided to start looking into making a python discord bot and I decided to invest some time looking into the free code camp course showing how to get the basics down. My problem is that when I've made the main.py, and the .env I have no visual errors in the code, but when I run it, I get this.

```
$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\documents\python\Burger Bot\main.py", line 18, in <module>
    client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
  File "C:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 718, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 697, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 660, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\keith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 509, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

My environment variable looks like how you would expect, TOKEN=[my token].
and the script is the exact same apart from the prefix at the beginning of the hello command. but here it is.

```py
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('?hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

I can't tell if I'm doing something wrong, but I am working on this locally, but I have tried it on replit. But I still get the same result.
Could anyone tell my what my problem is? ##

Comment: the error says that `os.getenv('TOKEN')` is null, check `dotenv` module to load from `.env` files, `.env` files and system env are 2 different things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the token from the `.env` file you should use [`python-dotenv`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)

Import it

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```

And load the file

```py
load_dotenv() # You can put this wherever you want, but before retrieving the token
```

Everything else should be as it is

Comment: Would I use something like this?
load_dotenv('./.env', ['TOKEN'])

Comment: What are you trying to do with that? `load_dotenv` alone should do it, to get the token you use the `os.getenv` function `token = os.getenv("TOKEN")`